# Given a pair of integers, minimum # of operations performed to reach target N

Tags: algorithm, math

Given a pair of numbers (A, B). 
You can perform an operation (A + B, B) or (A, A + B). 
(A, B) is initialized to (1, 1). 
For any N > 0, find the minimum number of operations you need to perform on (A, B) until A = N or B = N

Came across this question in an interview summary on glassdoor.  Thought through a couple approaches, searched online but couldn't find any articles/answers solving this question.  I have a brute force method shown below, however it must traverse O(2^N) paths, wondering if there is an elegant solution I am not seeing.

```
def pairsum(N):
    A = 1
    B = 1

    return helper(N, A, B, 0)

def helper(N, A, B, ops):
    # Solution found
    if A == N or B == N:
        return ops

    # We've gone over, invalid path taken
    if A > N or B > N:
        return float("inf")

    return min(helper(N, A + B, B, ops + 1), helper(N, A, A + B, ops + 1))
```

Comment: Your question as written is too broad. It would help if you show your brute-force solution--not because "anyone is interested" but to show your own work so far.

Comment: Hint: consider the binary representation of A, B, and N.

Comment: Hey @RoryDaulton, I edited to add simple example of solution (basically explore all possible ops that are "1 state" away until we reach N or go over N), then we calculate min between each path taken.

Comment: @barrycarter interesting, nothing is coming to mind yet but i'll keep pondering

Comment: Thanks for showing your work. I have voted to reopen this question--we'll see if enough other votes come. My explorations show that your algorithm has time complexity a little greater than O(N^2), much lower than what you state. The resulting sequence is given [here at oeis.org](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C3%2C5%2C4%2C4%2C5%2C5%2C5%2C5%2C5%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C7%2C6&sort=&language=english&go=Search). There does not seem to be a shortcut formula for the sequence and I cannot think of a better algorithm than yours in terms of time,...

Comment: (con'td) the main problem seems to be that of the size of the recursion stack. That problem could be avoided by calculating the Farey sequence in memory as a list, which spreads the memory out rather than up in a stack.

Comment: @barrycarter: You may have overlooked the fact that `A` and `B` are initialized to `1` at the start, so they are bound, intermediate variables and thus the answer depends only on `N`. I made that same mistake at first. Also, the problem seems more complex than you make it out. Could you flesh out your idea more, for my sake if not for the OP's?

Comment: I didn't overlook that. I originally thought you could build up 2^n fairly easily and then add binary digits, but that may not actually work (it was just a thought). Now it seems like the Fibonacci numbers may be involved.

Comment: The question is still too broad. If that is working code, you might migrate/re-ask on code-review. But check their FAQ first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a target number `N`, it's possible to compute the minimum number of operations in approximately `O(N log(N))` basic arithmetic operations (though I suspect there are faster ways). Here's how:

For this problem, I think it's easier to work backwards than forwards. Suppose that we're trying to reach a target pair `(a, b)` of positive integers. We start with `(a, b)` and work backwards towards `(1, 1)`, counting steps as we go. The reason that this is easy is that there's only ever a single path from a pair `(a, b)` back to `(1, 1)`: if `a > b`, then the pair `(a, b)` can't be the result of the second operation, so the only way we can possibly reach this pair is by applying the first operation to `(a - b, b)`. Similarly, if `a < b`, we can only have reached the pair via the second operation applied to `(a, b - a)`. What about the case `a = b`? Well, if `a = b = 1`, there's nothing to do. If `a = b` and `a > 1`, then there's no way we can reach the pair at all: note that both operations take coprime pairs of integers to coprime pairs of integers, so if we start with `(1, 1)`, we can never reach a pair of integers that has a greatest common divisor bigger than 1.

This leads to the following code to count the number of steps to get from `(1, 1)` to `(a, b)`, for any pair of positive integers `a` and `b`:

```
def steps_to_reach(a, b):
    """
    Given a pair of positive integers, return the number of steps required
    to reach that pair from (1, 1), or None if no path exists.
    """
    steps = 0
    while True:
        if a > b:
            a -= b
        elif b > a:
            b -= a
        elif a == 1:  # must also have b == 1 here
            break
        else:
            return None  # no path, gcd(a, b) > 1
        steps += 1
    return steps
```

Looking at the code above, it bears a strong resemblance to the Euclidean algorithm for computing greatest common divisors, except that we're doing things very inefficiently, by using repeated subtractions instead of going directly to the remainder with a Euclidean division step. So it's possible to replace the above with the following equivalent, simpler, faster version:

```
def steps_to_reach_fast(a, b):
    """
    Given a pair of positive integers, return the number of steps required
    to reach that pair from (1, 1), or None if no path exists.

    Faster version of steps_to_reach.
    """
    steps = -1
    while b:
        a, (q, b) = b, divmod(a, b)
        steps += q
    return None if a > 1 else steps
```

I leave it to you to check that the two pieces of code are equivalent: it's not hard to prove, but if you don't feel like getting out pen and paper then a quick check at the prompt should be convincing:

```
>>> all(steps_to_reach(a, b) == steps_to_reach_fast(a, b) for a in range(1, 1001) for b in range(1, 1001))
True
```

The call `steps_to_reach_fast(a, b)` needs `O(log(max(a, b)))` arithmetic operations. (This follows from standard analysis of the Euclidean algorithm.)

Now it's straightfoward to find the minimum number of operations for a given `n`:

```
def min_steps_to_reach(n):
    """
    Find the minimum number of steps to reach a pair (*, n) or (n, *).
    """
    # Count steps in all paths to (n, a). By symmetry, no need to
    # check (a, n) too.
    all_steps = (steps_to_reach_fast(n, a) for a in range(1, n+1))
    return min(steps for steps in all_steps if steps is not None)
```

This function runs reasonably quickly up to `n = 1000000` or so. Let's print out the first few values:

```
>>> min_steps_to_reach(10**6)  # takes ~1 second on my laptop
30
>>> [min_steps_to_reach(n) for n in range(1, 50)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8]
```

A search at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org) quickly yields the sequence [A178047](http://oeis.org/A178047), which matches our sequence perfectly. The sequence is described as follows:

> Consider the Farey tree A006842/A006843; a(n) = row at which the
>   denominator n first appears (assumes first row is labeled row 0).

And indeed, if you look at the tree generated by your two operations, starting at `(1, 1)`, and you regard each pair as a fraction, you get something that's very similar to the [Stern-Brocot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree) tree (another name for the Farey tree): the contents of each row are the same, but the ordering within each row is different. As it turns out, it's the [Stern-Brocot tree in disguise](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/b-tree.shtml)!

This observation gives us an easily computable lower-bound on `min_steps_to_reach`: it's easy to show that the largest integer appearing as either a numerator or denominator in the `i`th row of the Stern-Brocot tree is the `i+2`nd Fibonacci number. So if `n > Fib(i+2)`, then `min_steps_to_reach(n) > i` (and if `n == Fib(i+2)`, then `min_steps_to_reach(n)` is *exactly* `i`). Getting an upper bound (or an exact value without an exhaustive search) seems to be a bit harder. Here are the worst cases: for each integer `s >= 0`, the smallest `n` requiring `s` steps (so for example, `506` is the first number requiring `15` steps):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 14, 20, 28, 38, 54, 90, 150, 216, 350, 506, 876, 1230, 2034, 3160, 4470, 7764]
```

If there's a pattern here, I'm not spotting it (but it's essentially sequence [A135510](http://oeis.org/A135510) on OEIS).

Comment: sweet jesus.  Thank you, awesome explanation + analysis.  I have accepted this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[I wrote this before I realized @mark-dickinson had answered; his answer is much better than mine, but I'm providing mine for reference anyway]

The problem is fairly easy to solve if you work backwards. As an example, suppose N=65:

- That means our current pair is either {65, x} or {y, 65} for some unknown values of x and y.
- If {A,B} was the previous pair, this means either {A, A+B} or {A+B, B} is equal to either {65, x} or {y, 65}, which gives us 4 possible cases:

  - {A,A+B} = {65,x}, which would mean A=65. However, if A=65, we would've already hit A=N at an earlier step, and we're assuming this is the first step at which A=N or B=N, so we discard this possibility.
  - {A,A+B} = {y,65} which means A+B=65
  - {A+B,B} = {65,x} which means A+B=65
  - {A+B,B} = {y,65} which means B=65. However, if B=65, we already had a solution at a previous step, we also discard this possibility.

Therefore, A+B=65. There are 65 ways in which this can happen (actually, I think you can ignore the cases where A=0 or B=0, and also choose B>A by symmetry, but the solution is easy even withouth these assumptions).

- We now examine all 65 cases. As an example, let's use A=25 and B=40.
- If {C,D} was the pair that generated {25,40}, there are two possible cases:

  - {C+D,D} = {25,40} so D=40 and C=-15, which is impossible, since, starting at {1,1}, we will never get negative numbers.
  - {C,C+D} = {25,40} so C=25, and D=15.
- Therefore, the "predecessor" of {25,40} is necessarily {25,15}.
- By similar analysis, the predecessor of {25,15}, let's call it {E,F}, must have the property that either:

  - {E,E+F} = {25,15}, impossible since this would mean F=-10
  - {E+F,F} = {25,15} meaning E=10 and F=15.
- Similarly the predecessor of {10,15} is {10,5}, whose predecessor is {5,5}.
- The predecessor of {5,5} is either {0,5} or {5,0}. These two pairs are their own predecessors, but have no other predecessors.
- Since we never hit {1,1} in this sequence, we know that {1,1} will never generate {25, 40}, so we continue computing for other pairs {A,B} such that A+B=65.
- If we did hit {1,1}, we'd count the number of steps it took to get there, store the value, compute it for all other values of {A,B} such that A+B=65, and take the minimum.

Note that once we've chosen a value of A (and thus a value of B), we are effectively doing the subtraction version of [Euclid's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations), so the number of steps required is O(log(N)). Since you are doing these steps N times, the algorithm is O(N*log(N)), much smaller than your O(2^N).

Of course, you may be able to find shortcuts to make the method even faster.

### Interesting Notes

If you start with {1,1}, here are the pairs you can generate in k steps (we use k=0 for {1,1} itself), after removing duplicates:

k=0: {1,1}

k=1: {2, 1}, {1, 2}

k=2: {3, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 3}

k=3: {4, 1}, {3, 4}, {5, 3}, {2, 5}, {5, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 3}, {1, 4}

k=4: {5, 1}, {4, 5}, {7, 4}, {3, 7}, {8, 3}, {5, 8}, {7, 5}, {2, 7}, {7, 2}, {5, 7}, {8, 5}, {3, 8}, {7, 3}, {4, 7}, {5, 4}, {1, 5}

k=5: {6, 1}, {5, 6}, {9, 5}, {4, 9}, {11, 4}, {7, 11}, {10, 7}, {3, 10}, {11, 3}, {8, 11}, {13, 8}, {5, 13}, {12, 5}, {7, 12}, {9, 7}, {2, 9}, {9, 2}, {7, 9}, {12, 7}, {5, 12}, {13, 5}, {8, 13}, {11, 8}, {3, 11},  {10, 3}, {7, 10}, {11, 7}, {4, 11}, {9, 4}, {5, 9}, {6, 5}, {1, 6}

Things to note:

- You can generate N=7 and N=8 in 4 steps, but not N=6, which requires 5 steps.
- The number of pairs generated is 2^k
- The smallest number of steps (k) required to reach a given N is:

N=1: k=0

N=2: k=1

N=3: k=2

N=4: k=3

N=5: k=3

N=6: k=5

N=7: k=4

N=8: k=4

N=9: k=5

N=10: k=5

N=11: k=5

The resulting sequence, {0,1,2,3,3,5,4,4,5,5,5,...} is https://oeis.org/A178047

- The highest number generated in k steps is the (k+2)nd Fibonacci number, http://oeis.org/A000045
- The number of distinct integers you can reach in k steps is now the (k+1)st element of http://oeis.org/A293160
- As an example for k=20:

  - There are 2^20 or 1048576 pairs when k=20
  - The highest number in any of the 1048576 pairs above is 17711, the 22nd (20+2) Fibonacci number
  - However, you can't reach all of the first 17711 integers with these pairs. You can only reach 11552 of them, the 21st (20+1) element of A293160

For details on how I worked this problem out, see https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/STACK/bc-add-sets.m

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed breakdown of the problem!  For fairness, I have marked Mark Dickinson's answer as correct since he submitted first. :)

Comment: I made 2 major errors which I've now struck out and plan to fix.

Comment: I've now fixed the "interesting notes" section to be accurate